# Multiple IF statements in a excel formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Outcomes to asses if NCW-reports are finished in time or not *column E* contains either a date or not, if a date is entered the report is finished. *column F* contains the target date, by which date the report should be finished.
I am trying to formulate a formula that tests 3 cells with 4 possible outcomes.

- NCW Open
- Closed Overdue
- Closed in time
- Closed Overdue

I have got a data-set where `=TODAY()` is set in *cell B1* and my data set date in *column E* (is either blank of contains a close date) and *F* (contains the target date). 
The formula needs to check if cell in *column E* is blank if blank then check target date against `=TODAY()` in *B2*. Is =TODAY() before or after the date in *F*

If a date is in a cell in *column E*, disregard *B1*, but check if the date in *E* is before or after the target date in *F*.

Currently I came up with the following formula, but does not work it only returns NCW Open and Closed Overdue

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(E3)=TRUE,E3>=$B$1),"Open Overdue", IF(AND(ISBLANK(E3)=TRUE,E3<=$B$1),"NCW Open", IF(AND(ISBLANK(E3)=FALSE,F3>=E3,),"Closed in Time","Closed Overdue")))
```

[Left table: Current outcome with the formula. Right table: Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKRoQ.png)

Comment: Closed Overdue is a duplicate outcome?

Comment: What does "in range of the target date in F" mean? Refactoring the non-working formula is hard. Can you step back, edit your question to enter a few data samples and manually enter the expected results, then explain the logic that leads to the results. That will be much more helpful than a wall of text and a non-working formula

Comment: the formula returns Closed Overdue whenever there is a date in <i>column E</i> and returns NCW Open whenever a cell in <i>column E</i> is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the formula, you can use 1 nested IF() only in each condition. See formula for cell G3:

```
=IF(MIN(TODAY(),E3)>F3,IF(ISBLANK(E3),"Open Overdue","Closed Overdue"),IF(ISBLANK(E3),"NCW Open","Closed in time"))
```

The formula first checks if the item is overdue or not, and in the second if for each result if it's open or closed. See the results:

[image]